# What <con:originalUri> used in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

During testing web services using SoapUI. I saw in the SoapUI project a node named `<con:originalUri>` is generated. Does anyone know how to replace the value inside the node to avoid hardcode?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqn6l.png)

Comment: You say a node in the project. Is it a node in the request XML ?

Comment: @ou_ryperd The The node is the project, After sending a request the node is generated.